# Iterate through subdirectories in bash

Tags: bash, grep

How can we iterate over the subdirectories of the given directory and get file within those subdirectories in bash. Can I do that using grep command?

Answer (score 18):

This will go one subdirectory deep. The inner `for` loop will iterate over enclosed files and directories. The `if` statement will exclude directories. You can set options to include hidden files and directories (`shopt -s dotglob`).

```
shopt -s nullglob
for dir in /some/dir/*/
do
    for file in "$dir"/*
    do
        if [[ -f $file ]]
        then
            do_something_with "$file"
        fi
    done
done
```

This will be recursive. You can limit the depth using the `-maxdepth` option.

```
find /some/dir -mindepth 2 -type f -exec do_something {} \;
```

Using `-mindepth` excludes files in the current directory, but it includes files in the next level down (and below, depending on `-maxdepth`).

Comment: if I replace do_something with dos2unix, I get `find: missing argument to `-exec'`. However, I need a file for dos2unix. So maybe find will not work, but the loop. But I want to go deep to the folders.

Comment: @Timo: It works for me. What is your full command? It's possible that you left off the `\;` (and don't forget the `{}`).

Answer (score 3):

Well, you **can** do that using `grep`:

```
grep -rl ^ /path/to/dir
```

But why? `find` is better.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [find(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Answer (score -1):

I am on mac terminal, none of the above worked for me . If someone is trying on mac terminal like me here is is what worked for me:

```
p=$(pwd);arrayname=( $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d ) );for element in $(seq 0 $((${#arrayname[@]} - 1)));do echo "${arrayname[$element]}";cd "$p/${arrayname[$element]:2}"; pi=$(pwd); echo "i am inside: "$pi "I will do something here" ; cd ..; echo "Now i am outside: "$p ;done;
```

As suggested by @tripleee the following works too

```
for d in ./*/; do ( cd "$d"; echo "now I am here: $d"; ) ;done
```

Comment: This looks like an extremely convoluted way to say `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir sh -c 'echo "now I am here"'` or better yet `for d in ./*/; do ( cd "$d"; echo "now I am here"; ) done` (the latter will skip any dot directories; add `./.*/` to the wildcard if you want to include them; `for d in ./.*/ ./*/; do`...)

Comment: @tripleee my focus is to get it working first, then wonder if it's convoluted or revoluted. I couldn't get others to work even. Thanks for the suggestion, if I can get yours to work as well I will update my answer with it as it looks cleaner.

Comment: @tripleee this is the error I get running yours `find: -execdir: no terminating ";" or "+"`

Comment: Can't fix the comment but yeah, you need a terminating `\;` at the end.

Comment: Probably better to post a new question with your specific problem rather than try to figure out an answer where you cannot understand the other answers.

Comment: @tripleee where is the variable to print current directory , you code only prints "now I am here" repeatedly

Comment: It is unclear what exactly you hope to accomplish with the code but you can put any command you like in the `sh -c '...'` including `pwd`.

Comment: @tripleee we need to be able to do multi-line operations inside the loop. If I understand the question thats what it is all about. knowing the path is the first basic thing of any operation inside a loop

Comment: There are many, many situations where doing something in every directory does not require you to know which directory you are in. Again, probably post a new question with the actual problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @tripleee if attempted probably someone like you will mark that as duplicate and immediately close it. I would suggest you can create it, given that you have high reputation people will think twice before closing your question.

Comment: The reason I suggest this is because we cannot guess what you are actually trying to solve. Posting questions in comments on an answer is just a very ineffective way to get a solution. Your reputation makes no difference; just make sure you have a well-defined question and a reasonable attempt to solve it yourself. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: @tripleee I have already solved with my "convoluted" way and one of your ways which has path as variable. So I don't need to solve anything more. If you have of itch of splitting this question, hence I suggested so.